# How to generate a report on VAT collected (HST in my case)

Tags: reports

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious since I'm not an accountant or bookkeeper. I think I have everything set up to collect HST using the information at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/sales-tax-and-vat/

The correct rate is charged and the receipt the constituent gets all look good. However the bookkeeping transaction report shows everything except the HST part of the transaction. I've tried playing with filters and columns to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keith, Welcome to SE. Did you try [extended report extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports)? It provides additional reports with useful columns example

**Extended Report - Bookkeeping with extra fields**

[image]

HTH

Pradeep